Kerning problems regarding stencil combinations in LilyPond
When combining two stencils / shapes in lilypond, is it possible to set the padding between the two shapes based on the actual content of them instead of their bounding boxes? I would like the ideal padding to be the minimum horizontal distance between the actual content of the two shapes, not their bounding boxes, which is displayed as follows. The 2nd picture's effect is what I am looking for.



padding based on bounding box
padding based on content









Such effects can be seen when different symbols get combined in LilyPond. For example, the accidental before notes sometimes get interlocking when placed before a chord. SMuFL achieves this effect by the glyphsWithAnchors JSON configuration. Although there are some stencil-related functions in LilyPond like ly:stencil-stack, ly:stencil-combine-at-edge, these functions all operate on stencils based on their bounding boxes instead of their actual shape contents. So is there a function that can set padding based on the shape contents?


Lilypond is actually doing that for a lot of spacing problems using something they call skylines. Basically for any stencil you can get a horizontal skyline (i.e. a line above and below the stencil) and a vertical skyline (i.e. a line left and right to the stencil). It is more or less the big sibling of a bounding box.
Here you can see this in effect:
stc =
#(ly:stencil-rotate
  (make-path-stencil
   '(moveto 0 0 lineto 1 1 lineto 1 0 lineto 2 0 lineto 1 -1 closepath)
   0 1 1 #t)
  10 1 0)

#(define (stencil-add-bounds stc)
   (define (skyline->stencil sky axis)
     (let ((points
            (sort!
             (filter
               (lambda (x) (not (or (inf? (car x)) (inf? (cdr x)))))
               (ly:skyline->points sky axis))
             (if (= axis X)
                 (lambda (x y) (< (car x) (car y)))
                 (lambda (x y) (< (cdr x) (cdr y)))))))
       (make-path-stencil
        (apply
         append
         (cons
          `(moveto ,(caar points) ,(cdar points))
          (map
           (lambda (x)
             `(lineto ,(car x) ,(cdr x)))
           (cdr points))))
        (if (= axis X) 0.025 0.05) 1 1 #f)))
   (let* ((ext-x (ly:stencil-extent stc X))
          (ext-y (ly:stencil-extent stc Y))
          (real-ext-x (stencil-true-extent stc X))
          (real-ext-y (stencil-true-extent stc Y))
          (skylines-x (ly:skylines-for-stencil stc Y))
          (skylines-y (ly:skylines-for-stencil stc X))
          
          (box1
           (make-path-stencil
            `(moveto ,(car ext-x) ,(car ext-y)
              lineto ,(car ext-x) ,(cdr ext-y)
              lineto ,(cdr ext-x) ,(cdr ext-y)
              lineto ,(cdr ext-x) ,(car ext-y)
              closepath)
            0.03 1 1 #f))
          (box2
           (make-path-stencil
            `(moveto ,(car real-ext-x) ,(car real-ext-y)
              lineto ,(car real-ext-x) ,(cdr real-ext-y)
              lineto ,(cdr real-ext-x) ,(cdr real-ext-y)
              lineto ,(cdr real-ext-x) ,(car real-ext-y)
              closepath)
            0.02 1 1 #f))
          (sky-x1 (skyline->stencil (car skylines-x) Y))
          (sky-x2 (skyline->stencil (cdr skylines-x) Y))
          (sky-y1 (skyline->stencil (car skylines-y) X))
          (sky-y2 (skyline->stencil (cdr skylines-y) X))
          (sky-box-x (ly:stencil-add sky-x1 sky-x2))
          (sky-box-y (ly:stencil-add sky-y1 sky-y2)))
     (ly:stencil-add
      stc
      (ly:stencil-in-color box1 "red")
      (ly:stencil-in-color box2 "blue")
      (ly:stencil-in-color sky-box-x "green")
      (ly:stencil-in-color sky-box-y "yellow"))))

\markup \line {
  \vcenter\scale #'(6 . 6) \stencil #(stencil-add-bounds stc)
  \vcenter\column {
    "Red: Stencil extent (bounding box of stencil as given by extent pairs)"
    "Blue: True extend (bounding box of stencil by actual stencil content"
    "Green: Vertical skylines (X-extent per Y-position)"
    "Yellow: Horizontal skylines (Y-extent per X-position)"
  }
}


So using this we can achieve what you want: Instead of aligning the stencils in such a way that the distance of the bounding boxes is a certain padding we simply need to align them in a way such that the distance between the skylines is that padding. Luckily Lilypond does have a function to get the distance between two skylines, so this is only a matter of doing:
#(define (ly:stencil-combine-at-skyline stc1 stc2 axis padding)
   (let* ((skyline1 (ly:skylines-for-stencil stc1 (other-axis axis)))
          (skyline2 (ly:skylines-for-stencil stc2 (other-axis axis)))
          (dist (ly:skyline-distance (cdr skyline1) (car skyline2) padding)))
     (ly:stencil-add stc1 (ly:stencil-translate-axis stc2 dist axis))))

Testing this we get:
stc = #(make-path-stencil '(moveto 0 0 lineto 1 1 lineto 1 0 lineto 2 0 lineto 1 -1 closepath) 0 1 1 #t)

stcb = #(ly:stencil-scale (ly:stencil-translate-axis stc 0.5 Y) 1.5 1)

#(define (ly:stencil-combine-at-skyline stc1 stc2 axis padding)
   (let* ((skyline1 (ly:skylines-for-stencil stc1 (other-axis axis)))
          (skyline2 (ly:skylines-for-stencil stc2 (other-axis axis)))
          (dist (ly:skyline-distance (cdr skyline1) (car skyline2) padding)))
     (ly:stencil-add stc1 (ly:stencil-translate-axis stc2 dist axis))))

\markup \line {
  \column {
    \concat { \stencil #stc \stencil #stcb }
    \stencil #(ly:stencil-combine-at-edge stc X RIGHT stcb 0)
    \stencil #(ly:stencil-combine-at-skyline stc stcb X 0)
  }
  
  \column {
    \concat { \stencil #stc \stencil #stcb }
    \stencil #(ly:stencil-combine-at-edge stc X RIGHT stcb 0.1)
    \stencil #(ly:stencil-combine-at-skyline stc stcb X 0.1)
  }
  
  \column {
    \concat { \stencil #stc \stencil #stcb }
    \stencil #(ly:stencil-combine-at-edge stc X RIGHT stcb 0.2)
    \stencil #(ly:stencil-combine-at-skyline stc stcb X 0.2)
  }
}

#(define-markup-command (combine-at-skyline layout props pad mup1 mup2)
   (number? markup? markup?)
   (ly:stencil-combine-at-skyline
    (interpret-markup layout props mup1)
    (interpret-markup layout props mup2)
    X pad))

$(make-line-markup
  (map
   (lambda (i)
     (markup #:combine-at-skyline (/ i 5) "A" "V"))
   (iota 21)))

$(make-line-markup
  (map
   (lambda (i)
     (markup #:combine-at-skyline (/ i 5) "L" "T"))
   (iota 21)))

$(make-line-markup
  (map
   (lambda (i)
     (markup #:combine-at-skyline (/ i 5) "b" "t"))
   (iota 21)))


We can also adapt the function a bit to see what it is doing:
#(define (ly:stencil-combine-at-skyline stc1 stc2 axis padding)
   (define (skyline->stencil sky axis)
     (let ((points
            (sort!
             (filter
               (lambda (x) (not (or (inf? (car x)) (inf? (cdr x)))))
               (ly:skyline->points sky axis))
             (if (= axis X)
                 (lambda (x y) (< (car x) (car y)))
                 (lambda (x y) (< (cdr x) (cdr y)))))))
       (make-path-stencil
        (apply
         append
         (cons
          `(moveto ,(caar points) ,(cdar points))
          (map
           (lambda (x)
             `(lineto ,(car x) ,(cdr x)))
           (cdr points))))
        0.1 1 1 #f)))
   (let* ((skyline1 (ly:skylines-for-stencil stc1 (other-axis axis)))
          (skyline2 (ly:skylines-for-stencil stc2 (other-axis axis)))
          (dist (ly:skyline-distance (cdr skyline1) (car skyline2) padding)))
     (ly:stencil-add
      stc1 (ly:stencil-translate-axis stc2 dist axis)
      (ly:stencil-in-color (skyline->stencil (cdr skyline1) (other-axis axis)) "red")
      (ly:stencil-in-color
       (ly:stencil-translate-axis
        (skyline->stencil (car skyline2) (other-axis axis)) dist axis)
       "blue"))))


Note though that this still does only look at outlines of some sort over some projection. You can see this here:

While in the last case the L and the T could be still kerned together quite well it turns the function cannot do so, as it does not consider the whitespace under the serifs. A more powerful method would require calculating an actual outline of the stencil (e.g. as polygon approximation) and subsequently trying to solve for a minimal distance ensuring the minimum distance between any two points is equal to the padding. Note that clipping algorithms are highly non trivial. So this would not be particularly easy to get done.

Wow, this is perfect! I do sometimes see the word "skyline" while trying to modify certain grob attributes but I wasn't aware what is really is before. Thanks a lot! @Lazy

I've made a slight modification to the original code to produce the effect of keeping the two stencils' distance an arbitrary value.
#(define (ly:stencil-combine-at-skyline stc1 stc2 axis padding)    (let* ((skyline1 (ly:skylines-for-stencil stc1 (other-axis axis)))           (skyline2 (ly:skylines-for-stencil stc2 (other-axis axis)))           (dist (ly:skyline-distance (cdr skyline1) (car skyline2) 0)))      (ly:stencil-add stc1 (ly:stencil-translate-axis stc2 (+ dist padding) axis))))
